# How to Backup and Restore Bitnami Moodle on AWS ECS2

Tags: amazon-web-services, moodle, bitnami, amazon-ecs

I have Bitnami Moodle up and running on Amazon AWS ECS2 for about a year without a problem, I also have a LAMP Server installation, which I haven't done anything with yet.

I want to know how to Back Up my Bitnami Moodle so that I can bring down the server and reinstall a server with other Bitnami installations: Moodle, LAMP, and Wordpress.

Does a AWS ECS2 Snapshot back up Bitnami Moodle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bitnami developer here.

In order to backup/restore your server you should follow this guide:
https://docs.bitnami.com/aws/apps/moodle/#how-to-create-a-full-backup-of-moodle

Also, the aws ec2 snapshot should be something that you can apply to all your servers, so I think you won't have any problem to create some snapshots of your server:

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ebs-creating-snapshot.html

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer.  I'm new to Stackexchange, so just wondering how I leave feedback in relation to the help I've received?

Comment: Hi!
You can mark this answer as the solution and other users will benefit of this. Thanks so much!